# How do I separate a name of something with spaces and numbers from a number in a single line of a file?

Tags: c++, console

I have a file, it looks like this:

```
Car-in-blue 4
Truck 100 5
Jeep-43 434 6
Machine 123 5
```

The last digits of a line is an integer number that should be inserted into an int variable. The names containing hyphens, spaces, and numbers should be inserted into a string variable.

It should be like this:

```cpp
int a = 4
string name = "Car-in-blue"
```

```cpp
int a = 5
string name = "Truck 100"
```

```cpp
int a = 6
string name = "Jeep-43 434"
```

```cpp
int a = 5
string name = "Machine 123"
```

I added a screenshot of the original problem, it's not in English, but that doesn't matter, that's how it looks in the problem:

[image: Screenshot]

Text version:

```
Cap-de-bour 4
Romania 100 10
Cap-de-bour 7
Cap-de-bour 4
Romania 100 5
Romania 100 5
Romania 100 5
CRACIUN 2018 15
Romania 100 10
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are aware of std::getline() and std::stringstream?

Comment: I used as usual an, fin >> string_variable >> int_variable, in a cycle but after this understand that this wouldn't work and don't get another idea.

Comment: I'd use `getline` to read the entire line. Then use `find_last_not_of("0123456789");` to find the last character before the beginning of the final number. `substr` to get the parts before and after that, then `std::stoi` to convert the trailing part to an integer.

Comment: *"I don't have any ideas on the solving)"* -- If this is literally true, then the first thing you should do is read something -- anything -- from the file. Don't worry about getting the right data in the right variables; just get some data in some variable. *If you can already do this, then you **do** have a start on how to solve this, and you should include your best attempt so far. Make sure your best attempt includes definitions of `a` and `name` to help link your code to your text.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the safest code but detailed and clear:

The most convenient way to do this for me (that would only work for this example) is to put these things into a string, and then sort through the string in reverse.

I don't know how you're getting the information to begin with, but **if you need to grab it from a text file first do this code:**

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> //not sure if needed but I always include it

int main()
{
    std::vector<string> lines;
    std::string temp;
    ifstream is("FILENAME.txt");
    while (!is.eof()) //make sure it's not the end of the file (eof)
    {
        std::getline(is, temp); //get a line and toss it into "temp".
        lines.push_back(temp);//create new entry in our vector.
    }
}
```

Next to actually iterate:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<string> lines;
    string temp_string;
    ifstream is("FILENAME.txt");
    while (!is.eof()) //make sure it's not the end of the file (eof)
    {
        getline(is, temp_string); //get a line and toss it into "temp".
        lines.push_back(temp_string);//create new entry in our vector.
    }


    vector<string> model;
    vector<int> number;
    string line, temp_model;
    int temp_number;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        line = lines[i];
        temp_string = "";//reset string
        temp_number = 0;//reset integer
        for (int x = line.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--) //reverse iteration
        {
            if (line[x] == ' ')
            {
                //x now is the breaking point between the mode name and the number. use that to get model name now:
                temp_model = "";//reset string
                for (int c = 0; c < x/*to make surewe don't pass the stopping point*/; c++)
                {
                    temp_model += line[c];
                }

                break;//end loop
            }
            //if still for some reason need to check if it's a number, use std::isdigit()
            temp_string += line[x]; //adds the current character to our temporary string
        }


        //Reverse the string so that it's in proper order:
        for (int x = temp_string.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--);
        {
            //mini algorithm I came up with to store the number
            temp_number = 10 * temp_number;
            temp_number += stoi(temp_string); //attempt to convert string to integer (s to i)
        }
        number.push_back(temp_number);//store entry
        model.push_back(temp_model);//store entry
    }

    //output results:
    for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Model: " << model[i] << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << number[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenize your input lines, splitting them at the spaces.

Convert the last token to an integer and save

Recombine all but the last token into a string and save

```
    std::ifstream ifs ( -filepath- )
    std::string line;
    while (getline(ifs, line))
    {
        std::vector<std::string> vtoken;
        std::stringstream sst(line);
        std::string ta;
        while (getline(sst, ta, ' '))
                vtoken.push_back(ta);
        int a = atoi( vtoken.back().c_str());
        string name;
        for( auto it = vtoken.begin(); it != vtoken.end() - 1; it++ )
             name += " " + *it;
    }
```

You asked

> Is it okay to replace several spaces with one?

Modified tokenizer to handle multiple spaces as one:

```
        while (getline(sst, a, ' '))
            if (a.length())
                vtoken.push_back(a);
```

Comment: Suppose the line is `space city    `123    42` Is it okay to replace several spaces with one?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand.  Something wrong with the formatting of your comment.

Comment: Suppose a vehicle has two spaces in a row as part of its name. Suppose they belong there. That is what I meant with the `space city` example. Is it okay to combine multiple spaces into one?

Comment: If you want to keep the spaces use the un-modified tokenizer

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the update. I did not mean to nitpick. There may be advantages to condensing the spaces. I was thinking, however, about a contrasting file format, where vehicle `info` and vehicle `num` were stored _on different lines_. In that case, I would probably use `std::getline` to input vehicle `info`, and I would not parse it to eliminate double-spaces. So I asked myself, "Why would I eliminate double-spaces, just because the file format is something different?" (_Possible answer:_ Because it is convenient!)

Comment: You need to remember that your input files are not just read by code.  They also need to be readable by humans who are editing or checking for bugs.  If you do not condense spaces, then you are making spaces significant.  Humans have big problems noticing significant spaces - recall all the horrors of trying to find bugs in Python code with its significant white space.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about reading from a file:

> How do I separate a name of something with spaces and numbers from a number in a single line of a file?

This answer shows how to write a stream extraction operator that reads a line from a file, and parses it in the way you need. It uses a struct named `Vehicle` to hold the information from a record in the file. The struct defines `operator<<` and `operator>>` to handle I/O.

The struct has two fields: a string named `info` and an integer named `num`. `operator>>` extracts them both. As required, the integer is found at the end of a line, and all the characters preceding the integer (except for the spaces right before the integer) are taken to be the vehicle info.

`operator>>` is careful not to modify the vehicle info in any way. In particular, if the info contains double-spaces somewhere within it, they are preserved.

I tested using this data file:

```
Car-in-blue 4
Truck 100 5
Jeep-43 434 6
Machine 123 5
Double  space 990  42
```

And here is the program. It uses `std::getline` to read a line at a time from the file into string `s`. String `s` is then parsed using member functions `find_last_of` and `find_last_not_of`.

```cpp
// StackOverflow_77549120_Parse_Input_Answer.ixx
export module main;
import std;

struct Vehicle
{
    std::string info;
    int num;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, Vehicle const& v)
    {
        ost << v.info << ' ' << v.num << '\n';
        return ost;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& ist, Vehicle& v)
    {
        std::string s;
        if (!std::getline(ist, s))
            if (ist.eof())
                return ist;
            else
                throw std::runtime_error(
                    "`operator>>` failed - `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.");
        auto p{ s.find_last_of("0123456789") };
        if (p == std::string::npos)
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "`operator>>` failed - invalid line in file: \"" + s + '"');
        p = s.find_last_of(" /f/n/r/t/v", p);
        if (p == std::string::npos)
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "`operator>>` failed - invalid line in file: \"" + s + '"');
        std::stringstream sst(s.substr(p));
        if (!(sst >> v.num))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "`operator>>` failed - non-numeric characters at end of line: \"" + s + '"');
        if (!sst.eof())
            sst >> std::ws;
        if (!sst.eof())
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "`operator>>` failed - non-numeric characters at end of line: \"" + s + '"');
        p = s.find_last_not_of(" /f/n/r/t/v", p);
        if (p == std::string::npos)
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "`operator>>` failed - invalid line in file: \"" + s + '"');
        enum : std::string::size_type { zero, one };
        v.info = s.substr(zero, p + one);
        return ist;
    }
};
export int main()
{
    std::string data_file{ "StackOverflow_77549120_Parse_Input_data.txt" };
    std::ifstream ist{ data_file };
    if (!ist.is_open())
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "Error - Could not open data file: \"" + data_file + '"');
    Vehicle v;
    while (ist >> v)
    {
        std::cout
            << "Vehicle info : \"" << v.info << '"'
            << "\nVehicle num  : " << v.num
            << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
// end file: StackOverflow_77549120_Parse_Input_Answer.ixx
```

Output:

```
Vehicle info : "Car-in-blue"
Vehicle num  : 4

Vehicle info : "Truck 100"
Vehicle num  : 5

Vehicle info : "Jeep-43 434"
Vehicle num  : 6

Vehicle info : "Machine 123"
Vehicle num  : 5

Vehicle info : "Double  space 990"
Vehicle num  : 42
```